# Building an Connection string dynamically for MS Access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Our legacy system is in ms access I need to build a connection string dyanmically that is laoded from an ini file I have got the path ok from the ini file however how do I create a connecting string dynamically bare in mind the ini file could contain a unc path ie \servername\folder\db.mdb

Please no questions about why access this is a legacy system which I need to import into using .net

Can someone help please thanks

I have tried the follow but it fails to open the db

```
        Dim strFile As String = "C:\windows\figure.ini"
        Dim strRet As String
        Dim inifile As New IniFileManager

        strRet = inifile.ReadINI(strFile, "DATABASE SECTION", "FILENAME", "")

        Dim oleConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        oleConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

        oleConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                                                    "Data Source=" + strRet)

        Try
            oleConn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed to open Database")
        End Try
```

Comment: Instead of a generic "Failed to open Database" have your message box display `ex.Message` and then edit your question to tell us what it says.

Comment: @GordThompson it says its not registered on my machine however I can connect to it using visual studio etc. I am running windows 8.1

Comment: Have your application do `MsgBox(String.Format("{0}-bit", IntPtr.Size * 8))` and tell us what it says.

Comment: @GordThompson 64 bit mate

Answer (score 1):

As determined by the test in the comments to the question, the application is running as 64-bit and trying to use the older `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider. That will never work because there is no 64-bit version of the older Jet database engine. Therefore, your choices are

1. Tell Visual Studio to target the `x86` (32-bit) architecture (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)), and continue to use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider, or
2. Download and install the 64-bit version of the newer Microsoft Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and then use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider.